# What is wrong with this query in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following query

`query_posts('category_name='.$settings['categorieslider']&'posts_per_page='.$settings['numberofslides']);`

and for some reason it's not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try below code

```
query_posts('category_name='.$settings["categorieslider"].'&posts_per_page='.$settings['numberofslides']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write `cat` instead of `category_name`